# Using R to filter/keep colored cells in Excel file

Tags: r, excel, colors

Let's say I have an [excel workbook](https://github.com/dylangomes/SO/blob/main/SpeciesByYear_Colored.xlsx?raw=TRUE) with colored cells:

[image]

and I would only like to keep the colored cells, such that I would end up with the following dataframe:

```
   Species    Year  value
   <chr>      <chr> <dbl>
 1 Albacore   2014     38
 2 Albacore   2015     30
 3 Albacore   2017     24
 4 Albacore   2018     49
 5 Albacore   2019     18
 6 Blue Shark 1999      1  ## note these are cut off in the screenshot
 7 Blue Shark 2000      9  ## note these are cut off in the screenshot
 8 Blue Shark 2002     18
 9 Blue Shark 2003      2
10 Blue Shark 2006     11
# ... with 124 more rows
```

How can I do this with R?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a long answer, and somewhat clunky, but it works.

This post [Using R to read out excel-colorinfo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42982344/9096420) shows how to pull the color information as a vector, but we want to align this vector with our data frame and then create an index to filter our cells by.

First read in `DataSet` as a dataframe (which we will work with later) and the same workbook `wb` with `xlsx::loadWorkbook` which will allow us to pull color information (following the above link).

```
library(openxlsx)
library(xlsx)
library(tidyr)

DataSet<-openxlsx::read.xlsx("SpeciesByYear_Colored.xlsx")
wb<-xlsx::getSheets(xlsx::loadWorkbook("SpeciesByYear_Colored.xlsx"))[[1]]
```

Then from the above SO link, we pull the color information out as a vector:

```
rows<-getRows(wb)
cells<-getCells(rows)
styles <- sapply(cells, getCellStyle)

cellColor <- function(style) 
{
  fg  <- style$getFillForegroundXSSFColor()
  rgb <- tryCatch(fg$getRgb(), error = function(e) NULL)
  rgb <- paste(rgb, collapse = "")
  return(rgb)
}
colors<-sapply(styles, cellColor)
```

Now let's look at the vector

```
> head(colors,n=100)
     1.1      1.2      1.3      1.4      1.5      1.6      1.7      1.8 
      ""       ""       ""       ""       ""       ""       ""       "" 
     1.9     1.10     1.11     1.12     1.13     1.14     1.15     1.16 
      ""       ""       ""       ""       ""       ""       ""       "" 
    1.17     1.18     1.19     1.20     1.21     1.22     1.23     1.24 
      ""       ""       ""       ""       ""       ""       ""       "" 

    ...

    2.32     2.33     2.34     2.35     2.36     2.37     2.38     2.39 
      ""       ""       ""       ""       ""       ""       ""       "" 
    2.40     2.41     2.42     2.43     2.44     2.45     2.46     2.47 
      ""       ""       ""       "" "70ad47" "70ad47"       "" "70ad47" 
    2.48     2.49      3.1      3.2 
"70ad47" "70ad47"       ""       ""
```

The first number in this named vector is the row number and the second (after the `.`) is the column number. We need to pull this information out. Within quotes is the color code.
So we turn this into a dataframe and add row and column information with [regular expressions](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/vignettes/regular-expressions.html) (specifically [backreferencing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38681588/9096420)):

```
dat<-as.data.frame(colors)
dat$rows<-as.numeric(gsub(pattern = "([0-9]+).([0-9]+)",replacement ="\\1", row.names(dat)))
dat$cols<-as.numeric(gsub(pattern = "([0-9]+).([0-9]+)",replacement ="\\2", row.names(dat)))

> head(dat)
    colors rows cols
1.1           1    1
1.2           1    2
1.3           1    3
1.4           1    4
1.5           1    5
1.6           1    6
```

Now we can check that the dimensions make sense:

```
> dim(dat)
[1] 3332    3
```

There are 3332 color values which almost corresponds to our `DataSet` dimensions:

```
> dim(DataSet)
[1] 67 49

> 67*49
[1] 3283
```

Why doesn't this match? The color values include the header row (Years), while in `DataSet`, they are 'outside' the dataframe and contained in column names, so we need to add a row to our calculation to get the values to match:

```
> (67+1)*49
[1] 3332
```

This is important to keep in mind as we will see shortly.

Here I only have two colors `"70ad47" == green` and `"" == no fill`
So I will create a `blanks` object that will include cells to be removed.

```
blanks<-dat[dat$colors!="70ad47",]  ## OR: blanks<-dat[dat$colors=="",]
```

I then remove the first column, which is a valuable index (col 1) == `Species`. Then same for the first row, which includes the headers (`Year`). We *don't* want to remove these, which is why we remove them here from the removal list (a little convoluted).

```
blanks<-blanks[which(blanks$cols!=1),] 
blanks<-blanks[which(blanks$rows!=1),]
```

Now here is the trick, we now have to move the index down one because `DataSet` starts with row 1 of data as row = 1, whereas in the other dataset called `dat`, the header row was row 1 and the first row of data is row 2.

```
blanks$rows<-blanks$rows-1
```

Now we turn every observation in `DataSet` with no fill color to having a value of -1 (or any other useful value that we can later filter by)

```
for(i in 1:dim(blanks)[1]){
  DataSet[blanks$rows[i],blanks$cols[i]]<- -1 
}
```

We can then turn to long format to easily remove cells we aren't interested in

```
DataSet.Long<-DataSet %>% pivot_longer(cols=`1967`:`2019`,names_to = "Year")
> DataSet.Long
# A tibble: 3,216 x 3
   Species  Year  value
   <chr>    <chr> <dbl>
 1 Albacore 1967     -1
 2 Albacore 1972     -1
 3 Albacore 1973     -1
 4 Albacore 1974     -1
 5 Albacore 1975     -1
 6 Albacore 1977     -1
 7 Albacore 1978     -1
 8 Albacore 1979     -1
 9 Albacore 1980     -1
10 Albacore 1981     -1
# ... with 3,206 more rows
```

Now only keep values above -1

```
DataSet.Truncated<-DataSet.Long[DataSet.Long$value>-1,] 


> DataSet.Truncated
# A tibble: 134 x 3
   Species    Year  value
   <chr>      <chr> <dbl>
 1 Albacore   2014     38
 2 Albacore   2015     30
 3 Albacore   2017     24
 4 Albacore   2018     49
 5 Albacore   2019     18
 6 Blue Shark 1999      1
 7 Blue Shark 2000      9
 8 Blue Shark 2002     18
 9 Blue Shark 2003      2
10 Blue Shark 2006     11
# ... with 124 more rows
```

Comment: Nice answer. You can use tidyr::separate to convert rownames (row.col) to rwo separate columns more efficiently. Since you are using tidyverse anyway, it's not a bad idea to create a single pipeline, maybe as an addition to what you have now, to make the answer more legible. Cheers +1